# Union of two bounded sets is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space, for a nonempty subset $A$ of $X$, define

$$ \delta(A) = \sup_{x, y \in A} d(x,y) $$

$A$ is bounded if $\delta(A) < \infty $. If $A$, $B$ are bounded, does it follow that $A \cup B$ is bounded ? I know that $A \cap B$ is bounded since $A \cap B \subseteq B$, and the fact that $A \subseteq B \implies \delta(A) \leq \delta(B) $. But how about the $\cup$ ?

thanks

Comment: Yes. It's bounded by $\delta(A)+\delta(B)+c$, where $c$ is the distance between  a fixed point  of $A$ and a fixed point of $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And, in order to prove David Mitra's answer, you should:

- Use the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_inequality) .
- Convince yourself of the following fact:

$$
\mathrm{sup}_{x\in A,y\in B} \left\{ x + y\right\} \leq \mathrm{sup}_{x\in A} \left\{ x \right\} + \mathrm{sup}_{y\in B} \left\{ y\right\} \ .
$$

**EDIT.** And the second inequality comes from the fact that, for all $x\in A$ and all $y\in B$, you have

$$
x + y \leq \mathrm{sup}_{x\in A} \left\{ x \right\} + \mathrm{sup}_{y\in B} \left\{ y\right\} \ .
$$

Now, apply $\mathrm{sup}_{x\in A,y\in B}$ to both sides of this inequality and you are done.

**Exercise.** Why don't you have, in general, an equality

$$
\mathrm{sup}_{x\in A,y\in B} \left\{ x + y\right\} = \mathrm{sup}_{x\in A} \left\{ x \right\} + \mathrm{sup}_{y\in B} \left\{ y\right\} \quad \text{?}
$$

:-)

Comment: can you show your second bullet? It is hard for me to convince about it so easily. thanks

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

Let's $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ be fixed. Take any $x\in A , y\in B$, then $$d(x,y) \leq d(x,a ) +d(a,b) +d(b,y) \leq \delta (A) +d(a,b) +\delta (B)$$
thus $A\cup B$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

I would reason as follows:
$$\delta(A\cup B)=\sup(\delta(A),\delta(B),\sup_{a\in A, b\in B}d(a,b))$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are bounded, then, by definition, $\delta(A) < \infty$ and $\delta(B) < \infty$. One of the axioms of metric spaces ([Kreyszig, 1978](http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/spns/cdm/resources/Kreyszig%20-%20Introductory%20Functional%20Analysis%20with%20Applications.pdf), page 3, axiom (M1)) is: "$d$ [the metric] is real-valued, **finite** and nonnegative". Therefore, $\sup_{a\in A, b \in B}d(a,b) < \infty$, so it follows that $\delta(A \cup B) < \infty$, which means that $A\cup B$ is bounded.